Let $G$ be a group acting transitively on a set. Prove that the normalizer of a stabilizer acts transitively on set of points fixed by the stabilizer
There are actually two parts to the question, and I got the first part. Here is the full question:
Let $G$ be a finite group acting transitively on a set $\Omega$. Fix $\alpha\in \Omega$ and let $G_\alpha$ be the stabilizer of $\alpha$ in $G$. Let $\Delta$ be the set of points fixed by $G_\alpha$, i.e. $\Delta=\{\beta\in \Omega:x\beta=\beta~\forall x\in G_\alpha\}$. Show that $\Delta$ is stabilized by $N_G(G_\alpha)$ and that $N_G(G_\alpha)$ acts transitively on $\Delta$.
Here is my proof that $\Delta$ is stabilized by $N_G(G_\alpha)$:
Let $g\in N_G(G_\alpha)$, and let $\beta\in \Delta$. We want to show that $g\beta\in \Delta$. Let $h\in G_\alpha$. By definition of $N_G(G_\alpha)$, there is $h'\in G_\alpha$ such that $g^{-1}hg=h'$, so that $hg=gh'$. Thus
$$hg\beta =gh'\beta=g\beta$$
so that $g\beta$ is fixed by an arbitrary element of $G_\alpha$, and $g\beta\in \Delta$.
But I am stuck at showing transitivity. I know that since the action of $G$ on $\Omega$ is transitive, and if $\beta,\lambda\in\Delta$, then there is $g\in G$ such that $g\beta=\lambda$. Also, $g$ is not in $G_\alpha$. I don't think I can say here that $g$ is in $N_G(G_\alpha)$. Any help is appreciated.

Since the action is transitive, any $\beta$ can be written as $h\alpha$ for some $h\in G$.
Prove: $G_{h\alpha}=hG_\alpha h^{-1}$ for all $h\in G$.
Thus, $G_\alpha$ stabilises $h\alpha$ if and only if $G_\alpha\subseteq hG_\alpha h^{-1}$.
But when we're talking about two finite subgroups of the same size, saying $G_\alpha\subseteq hG_\alpha h^{-1}$ is the same as saying $G_\alpha=hG_\alpha h^{-1}$.
In conclusion, $G_\alpha$ stabilises $h\alpha$ if and only if $h$ is in the normaliser of $G$.
Do you see how the statements desired are simply a reformulation of this conclusion?

Oh you beat me to it.

If $\beta$ is fixed by $G_\alpha$ then $G_\alpha\leqslant G_\beta$, and so $G_\alpha= G_\beta$. Now let $g\in G$ carry $\alpha$ to $\beta$; then $G_\alpha^g= G_{g\alpha}=G_\beta=G_\alpha$; that is $g\in N_G(G_\alpha)$.
